# viewport под определенные разрешения

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно, чтобы контент на сайте, который меньше 480px масштабировался (как адаптивная картинка), а всё для того, чтобы элементы с макета уместились на маленьких экранах(соотвествие макету шириной 480px).Правильно ли заполнил тег viewport? Или есть более лучшие способы решения?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=479px, initial-scale=.7, width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: @Air Просто есть макет сайта шириной 480px, а на устройствах которые будут меньше 480px нужно сохранить такое же расположение элементов, без медиа запросов никак?

Comment: Сделал так:

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=480, initial-scale=1">

Задачу решает, но верный ли это подход. Просьба в комментариях ответить, кто знает

Comment: Верно...........